# How to loop through the following php array?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I want to loop through the following array.

```
array(2)  {
    [0]=> array(6) {
        [0]=> string(10) "excel_id "
        [1]=> string(12) "excel_name "
        [2]=> string(11) "excel_email"
        [3]=> string(13) "excel_address"
        [4]=> string(12) "excel_giveby"
        [5]=> string(16) "excel_accesories" 
    } 
    [1]=> array(6) {
        [0]=> float(111)
        [1]=> string(10) "sh1exname1"
        [2]=> string(11) "sh1exemail1"
        [3]=> string(12) "sh1exaddress"
        [4]=> string(12) "sh1exgivenby"
        [5]=> string(16) "sh1exaccesorries" 
    }    
}
```

can anyone help me?

Comment: try to use `foreach` loop at start

Comment: Please check here before asking a question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Have you even tried to look at the PHP manual on arrays ?

Comment: It is same as traversing an 2D array of size 2X6 in any other programing language. Use two loops and iterate through the whole array.

Comment: foreach ($data as $innerArray) {


         
      if (is_array($innerArray)){
          //  Scan through inner loop
          foreach ($innerArray as $value) {
              var_dump($value);
          }
      }else{
          
          echo $innerArray;
      }
  }

Answer (score 2):

If you tried anything at all you should have found foreach.
this will loop through all of your array values.
You can simply loop through a multi-dimensional array by using a multi-dimensional foreach like this:

```
foreach($array as $parentValue)
{
    foreach($parentValue as $childValue)
    {
        // your code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
foreach ($main_array as $outer_entry){

    foreach($outer_entry as $entity){
        print_r($entity);
    }

}
```